# Spring integration and JDBC in single transaction

Tags: spring, jdbc, transactions, rabbitmq, spring-integration

So the setup is following:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice2" transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" no-rollback-for="ListenerExecutionFailedException"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input-channel" queue-names="probni" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  advice-chain="txAdvice2" />

<int:chain input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="output-channel">
    <int:service-activator ref="h1Handler" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h2Handler" method="handle" />
    <int:service-activator ref="h3Handler" method="handle" />
    <int:splitter  />
</int:chain>

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="output-channel" exchange-name="outputit" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" />
```

If during the execution of this thread (since all this chain amqpIN-process-amqpOUT shold execute in single thread) I throw ListenerExecutionFailedException, dataSourceTransactionManager will do commit, but amqp will also requeue the message because the exception is propagated.

How can I tell rabbit to ACK the message as successful in this case?

Also, I saw that I had to put in no-rollback-for attribute actual exception class, since my inner-exception is only stored in "cause" attribute which is not inspected by the RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.

One more thing, if I make config like this:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input-channel" queue-names="probni" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager"
                                  transaction-attribute="transactionAttribute" />
```

transactionAttribute which is RuleBasedTransactionAttribute is not considered at all and dataSourceTransactionManager is always rollbacked even if I have no-rollback-for set correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom `ErrorHandler` to the listener container (<strike>you have to configure the container externally and provide a reference in the `container` attribute</strike>).

The default error handler is a `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` with a `DefaultExceptionStrategy` that considers certain LEFE cause exceptions as fatal:

```
    private boolean isCauseFatal(Throwable cause) {
        return cause instanceof MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
                || cause instanceof NoSuchMethodException
                || cause instanceof ClassCastException
                || isUserCauseFatal(cause);
    }
```

Starting with version 1.6.4 you can subclass the default `DefaultExceptionStrategy` and add your cause(s) to `isUserCauseFatal()`.

Before 1.6.4 you had to provide your own `FatalExceptionStrategy` (or error handler implementation).

For fatal causes, the handler throws a `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` which tells the container to nack (and not requeue) the message.

**EDIT**

By the way, there is no need for you to wrap the exception, the container will do that for you...

```
protected Exception wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(Exception e, Message message) {
    if (!(e instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException)) {
        // Wrap exception to ListenerExecutionFailedException.
        return new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Listener threw exception", e, message);
    }
    return e;
}
```

**EDIT2**

My mistake, the `ErrorHandler` can be specified using the `error-handler` attribute.

**EDIT3**

Alternatively, just throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` (which will be wrapped in the `LEFE`).

Comment: You don't need to wrap the exception; see my edit. Also, you can use the `error-handler` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Will try this tomorrow. If I do rejectAndDontRequeue - will this end up in DeadLetterQueue? I would like this to be treated as ordinary ACK, since I want to do this in case that message is redelivered (delivered at least once + possibly more). Do you know also, by the way, why transaction-attribute is not working on transaction when supplied inside inbound-channel-adater, but works if applied as advice? (The second part of the question).

Comment: That is if message is re-delivered but jdbc is already commited, I want to throw an exception that will rollback jdbc but ack rabbit message (since i do commit and ack at the end of processing pipeline).

Comment: Yes, it will go to the DLQ if so configured. If the error handler throws a `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException`, the message will be ack'd normally. I am not sure about your second question; AFAICT it should work ok, but I'll have to run some tests; but I am out of town this week. The `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` must __not__ be wrapped in a LEFE. The note in the exception javadoc "and without consuming any more messages" refers to `txSize` processing - it doesn't mean processing will stop.

Comment: The second issue is a bug; the container doesn't call the `rollbackOn` method on the transaction attribute. Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Extending AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException seems like the easiest solution here. If I throw ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException it is automatically wrapped in LEFE and I suppose I need to add logic to somehow unwrap it? Or you were talking about throwing this kind of exception inside ErrorHandler? Anyway this solution works and I opened JIRA issue - thanks one more time.

Comment: Yes, IAAE currently only works when thrown from an `ErrorHandler` - see [AMQP-686](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-686).